# Extract the data from the sublist into dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, extract, sublist

the structure of the list as follow (the list goes on with the same structure):

```
> str(parsedData)    
> List of 1658    
> $ :List of 2    
>  ..$ Date      : chr "2010-08-16"    
>  ..$ Volatility: num 11.1    
> $ :List of 2    
> ..$ Date      : chr "2010-08-17"    
> ..$ Volatility: num 26.2
```

as you can see, on the name of the first level of structure is empty space. I tried to extract the elements but fail:

```
> parsedData$Date    
>NULL
```

anyone can tell me how to extract only the Date and Volatility from this list (especially with no title) and put them all in the same dataframe like this? Thanks!

```
Date          Volatility     
2010-08-16    11.1    
2010-08-17    26.2    
...              ...
```

(this is the first time i ask question, sorry for any editing mistake :) )

Comment: @Metrics oh right! but how to extract all of them and put the min data.frame?

Comment: `rlist::list.stack(parsedData)` or `data.table::rbindlist(parsedData)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested:

`setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(1:length(parsedData),function(i)cbind(parsedData[[i]][1],parsedData[[i]][2])))),c("Date","Volatility")`

OR:

`setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(1:length(parsedData),function(i)t(parsedData[[i]][1:2])))),c("Date","Volatility"))`

Comment: Thanks, it works!! But can u tell me what "function(i)" means in this?

Comment: No problem. `i` indicates the iteration number (which goes from 1 to length of your list). You can use any alphabet or word instead of `i` to denote the iteration number.